# Word Macro VBA Finding specific style/list and converting to text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use a Word Macro to select all text with the style "Number_List" and call the `.ConvertNumbersToText` function on it. I am having trouble only finding the list or that specific style.

```
Dim selBkUp As Range
Set selBkUp = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Range.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Number_List")
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    Dim SearchSuccessful As Boolean
    SearchSuccessful = .Execute

    If SearchSuccessful Then
        selBkUp.Select
        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
    Else
        ' code
    End If
End With
```

I select the entire document and covert all of the lists numbers to text, but I am trying to only select ones with that specific style or avoid the other 5 styles that may or may not be present. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is:  '.ParagraphFormat.ra'

Comment: Typo, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will search for one style and, if found, will convert to another style.  Below this code is another subroutine that will list all styles found in a document.

```
' From http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?448185-Macro-to-Change-Styles-in-Word
' This code will search for a specified Style and convert that to another Style
Sub FindReplaceStyle()
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
         .Style = "Normal"                      ' Look for 'Normal'
         '.Text = ""
         .Replacement.Style = "Heading 1"       ' Change to 'Heading 1'
    '     .Replacement.Text = ""
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop
         .Format = True
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute()
        If Selection.Start = Selection.Paragraphs.First.Range.Start Then
            Selection.Style = "Heading 1"
        End If

        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop

End Sub
```

The code below will produce a list of all styles found in a document.

Also, I get an error trying to use your "Number_List"

```
' Following code from: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?41125-How-to-get-all-the-applied-Paragraph-Styles-of-a-document
 Sub GetActiveStyles()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim RngStory As Range, oSty As Style, StrType As String, StrStyles As String
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each oSty In .Styles
            For Each RngStory In .StoryRanges
                With RngStory.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = ""
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Style = oSty.NameLocal
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Format = True
                    .Execute
                    If .Found Then
                        Select Case oSty.Type
                        Case wdStyleTypeCharacter: StrType = "Character"
                        Case wdStyleTypeList: StrType = "list"
                        Case wdStyleTypeParagraph: StrType = "Paragraph"
                        Case wdStyleTypeTable: StrType = "Table"
                        End Select
                        StrStyles = StrStyles & oSty.NameLocal & " (" & StrType & ")" & vbCr
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End With
            Next RngStory
        Next oSty
    End With
    Debug.Print StrStyles
    'MsgBox StrStyles
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a custom style. Where does the list get produced?

Comment: Displayed in the Immediate window. You can un-comment the 'MsgBox' 2 line up from the bottom...

Comment: The style does exist. It is listed inside the produced Msgbox.

Comment: And your code spells it EXACTLY the same?  Does it show an underscore character?

Comment: I might've misspoke. My macro works-ish. My macro selects the entire document and then since the style I am looking for exists - it removes all the lists' styles instead of just the ones with Number_List. I would like it to ONLY "convernumbertotext" on Number_List and no other text if that makes more sense.

Comment: I update the answer with code I found (and tested) that will search for one style and change to another. Hope this helps. I am now heading offline for a few days...  Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Kind of confused on how it searches for a specific style? Unless 'oSty.NameLocal' should be replaced with my style and then I would like to remove all styles on it and call CovertNumbersToText so that the lists of numbers will just be text and never change.

Comment: I just stepped thru the code in 'GetActiveStyles' and there are 264 styles on my PC; for each one, it spins thru the document and searches for a match. If found, it will display that style name. In the 'FindReplaceStyle' code, you specify the name and it searches for it. I would run the code 'GetActiveStyles', get the proper spelling, then use the other code.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect. One last thing. I call 'Selection.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText' instead of 'Selection.Style = "Heading 1"' and it works perfectly except that all the lists turn to 1 because it selects each line individually so the next one automatically updates the list. Anyway to fix that? Maybe a quick Word setting?

Comment: Your code selects the entire document, thus the reason all of your lists get converted. Create a doc with multiple styles, put a breakpoint just after 'selBkUp.Select', run the code and when it stops, you will see the entire doc is selected.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. You say " I call 'Selection.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText' instead of 'Selection.Style = "Heading 1"' and it works perfectly except that all the lists turn to 1..."  I read that as you using "ConvertNumbersToText"and not using "Selection.Style..."?

Comment: Yes, so in your code it seems to be selecting line for line and if you select the first line of a list, the rest of the list (below it) will reset to 1. So as it goes down the list they all become 1. I need the list to stay the correct number and I can't have a style on it because the lists get messed up when merging documents.